# how to show button if username and email both available

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have form contain username and email and send button, i use Jquery to show availability for both of username and email :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#username").keyup(function(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    if(username.length >= 3){
        $.post("username_check.php", {username: username},
        function(data){
        $("#status").html(data).show();
        });
    }
});

$("#email").keyup(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if(email.length >= 3){
        $.post("email_check.php", {email: email},
        function(data2){
        $("#status2").html(data2).show();
        });
    }
});
});
```

the send button is disabled and i want to show it if both of email and username are available
How can i do that?
username_check.php page :

```
$username =$_POST['username']; 
$username = strip_tags($username);
$username = trim($username);
$username =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' ";
$result=mysqli_query($berikane,$sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);     
if($count==1 ){
    echo "Not Available";
     }
else {
    echo "Available";
    }?>
```

email_check.php page :

```
$email =$_POST['email']; 
$email = strip_tags($email);
$email = trim($email);
$email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' ";
$result=mysqli_query($berikane,$sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);           
if($count==1 ){
    echo "Not Available";
    }
else {
   echo "Available";
   }?>
```

Comment: I'm uncertain with the snippet provided how this code knows if the username and email are valid or not.  All I see are statuses being set, which I assume could happen for a good case or bad case.  How does this logic know the good cases?

Comment: i have 2 pages for checking and they are mentioned i post :username_check.php and email_check.php .. i don't have problem on showing availability

Comment: That's what I'm asking about though.  How does this logic know if the email is valid or not?  All the responses are going through the method that sets the status messages.  So is it the case that if an email or username is already taken that it will not go through that logic?

Comment: i edited the post ? is it right now?

Comment: Yep, so both the good case and the bad case are going through the method.  That's what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this potentially.  I don't know the selector for your button so I put a dummy selector in there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //cache the variables
  var $username = $('#username');
  var $email = $('#email');
  var $submitButton = $('selectorForTheSubmitButton');
  var usernameIsValid = false;
  var emailIsValid = false;

  //input happens any time the value changes, including pasting
  $username.on('input', function() {
    //disable the button, the value may be taken
    $submitButton.prop('disabled', true);
    //trim the username
    var username = $username.val().trim();

    if (username.length >= 3) {
      $.post("username_check.php", {
          username: username
        },
        function(data) {
          $("#status").html(data).show();
          //Available is the good case
          usernameIsValid = (data === 'Available');
          //Update the button disabled
          $submitButton.prop('disabled', !(usernameIsValid && emailIsValid));
        });
    }
  });

  $email.on('input', function() {
    $submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

    var email = $email.val().trim();

    if (email.length >= 3) {
      $.post("email_check.php", {
          email: email
        },
        function(data2) {
          $("#status2").html(data2).show();
          emailIsValid = (data === 'Available');
          //Update the button disabled
          $submitButton.prop('disabled', !(usernameIsValid && emailIsValid));
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check on this, migth be better than assigning a value to the property: [removeProp](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)
Update the code like:

```
 function(data2) {
      $("#status2").html(data2).show();
      //emailIsValid = (data === 'Available');
      emailIsValid = (data2 === 'Available');
      //Update the button disabled
      if (usernameIsValid && emailIsValid) {
          $submitButton.removeProp('disabled');
      }else{
          $submitButton.prop('disabled', true);  
      }
    });
```

Comment: I update the code, it should fix the issue before encountered.